# play2.3 doesn't work with file uploading form in production mode

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have a form in play framework 2.3, and there is a form to upload an image to the public folder with an HTML form.

This works in development mode.However, when i package the project with "play dist", the uploading doesn't work anymore because the public folder is packaged into the jar file.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution would be to use a Front End Proxy like Nginx in production environments. Some of the major benefits include,

- high performance delivery of static assets
- caching and compression
- load balancing